# Will a Handler defined in an Activity leak in this scenario

Tags: android

I've got an activity with a handler defined:

```
final Handler updateHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       // Do stuff.
    }
};
```

In my `onCreate` method, if I assign this handler to a static list outside of my Activity, will it leak (or rather, will that outside list keep a reference to my activity forever)? I.e,:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
      SomeStaticClass.addHandler(updateHandler);
}

...

public class SomeStaticClass {
    static List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();

    public static void addHandler(Handler handler) {
         handlers.add(handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my onCreate method, if I assign this handler to a static list outside of my Activity, will it leak (or rather, will that outside list keep a reference to my activity forever)?

Yes. Do not put `Handlers` in static data members.

Comment: Is there an alternative such as an event that is called when a view is "disposed" or not longer used by the OS? If so, I could unregister the handler, yes?

Comment: @Chu: "Is there an alternative such as an event that is called when a view is "disposed" or not longer used by the OS?" -- IMHO, whatever problem you think you are solving should be solved in some other way, other than putting `Handlers` in a static data member. Since you have not bothered to explain what it is you are attempting to achieve by this static list of `Handlers`, it is impossible for I or anyone else to give you suggestions of what it is you should really be doing here.

Comment: ok, I started a new question to address that exact same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557878/updating-a-view-from-a-handler-cleaning-up-the-mess